# DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb0 while calling the database procedure

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8

I am trying to call a postgres database procedure using psycopg2 in my python class.

lCursor.callproc('dbpackage.proc',[In_parameter1,In_parameter2,out_parameter]).

In_parameter values is 5008001#60°V4#FR.tif

But I am getting the below error.
DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb0

I have tried mostly solutions given on net, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoding and the database connection encoding don't match. The database connection is in UTF8 and you're probably trying to send with Latin1 encoding.

When opening the connection send `SET client_encoding TO 'Latin1'`, after that PostgreSQL will assume all strings to be in Latin1 encoding regardless of the database encoding.

Alternatively you can use `conn.set_client_encoding('Latin1')`

Comment: Thanks... it worked for me but its not necessary always that I will send a Latin1 encoding to database, it may be another encoding too. So is there any way in python that I can determine which encoding to be set to client at runtime by seeing the string.

Comment: @NikhilKrishnatrey The best way would be to handle everything in UTF-8 in the client end. But just by looking at a string it's not possible to know the encoding. Checking if it's valid UTF-8 or not is easy (valid doesn't mean it would be UTF-8 though).